# how to give a border to bootstrap tab contents

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using bootstrap tabs and it works perfectly.
I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use bootstrap to give a border to the contents of the tabs that is connected to the border of the pill so it will look like one box. 
I tried doing this with my own css, but there is a cap between the tab pill border and tab content border that is a margin the tab pill needs to have and can't be removed.
I want it to look like the below image.
[image: tab content with border]

Answer (score 103):

The following css should do exactly what you're looking for :)

```
.tab-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

***margin-bottom: 0;*** on *.nav-tabs* removes the gap in between the pills and content.

The *padding* on *.tab-content* makes the content not pressed against the new borders on the left and right.

Comment: thanks you so much. I have the exact same css but there is still a -1px margin for tab-nav li that creates that gap. It's very very small but I can still see it. Removing that, will mess up the tab lines. Well, maybe nobody but me will see it after all.

Comment: `.nav-tabs { margin-bottom: -1px; }` does it

Comment: If you want rounded borders at the bottom of the tab container to match the top, you can add `border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;` to `.tab-contents`

Comment: If using rounded borders, to get the top right rounded correctly, you should add the following: .tab-pane  {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

Answer (score 65):

I would modify Kisuka's answer to the following:

CSS

```
.tab-pane {

    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

SCSS for Bootstrap 4

```
.tab-pane {
    border-left: 1px solid $nav-tabs-border-color;
    border-right: 1px solid $nav-tabs-border-color;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $nav-tabs-border-color;
    border-radius: 0px 0px $nav-tabs-border-radius $nav-tabs-border-radius;
    padding: $spacer;
}

.nav-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With following code, all corner have radius, but tabs offset.

```
.nav-tabs {
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
}
.tab-content {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Caution: If you set nav-tab's padding-left 0px, first tab conflicts with left-top radius of contents.

Answer (score 5):

Being more DRY then @goat solution, you could also reuse the panel css like:

```
.tab-content.panel
{
    border-top: none; 
    border-top-left-radius: 0px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}


<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        ...
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content panel">
        <div class="tab-pane panel-body">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tab-content panel panel-default and tab-pane panel-body. Then you don't need to redefine the border and padding. Just remove the top border and top radius.

Answer (score 3):

This was asked a long time ago but the trick here might help some people:

Put in a `div.container` your `.nav-tabs` and `.tab-content`.
To that `div.container`, give a fixed height says **300px** and `border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc` and `overflow: hidden !important`.

Then to the `.tab-content`, I add this css: `height: 100%;  border-left: 1px solid #ccc ;   border-right: 1px solid #ccc;`

And it works. Try it out ( http://jsfiddle.net/996Bw/ )

Answer (score 3):

I modified the answer's by @user3749683 and @Kisuka so that you don't have to change the definition of any existing bootstrap styles. Instead, you just add a new class to the parent element. I used first child selectors so that you can have nested tabs that don't necessarily need to have the bordered content too.

```
.bordered-tab-contents > .tab-content > .tab-pane {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bordered-tab-contents > .nav-tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

markup structure

```
<div class="bordered-tab-contents">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        ...
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" ...>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Popnoodles answer, adding `.border .border-top-0` to `.tab-pane` also works in Bootstrap 4.3

```
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane border border-top-0">
      <!-- tab content -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

or in SCSS

```
.tab-pane {
  @extend .border;
  @extend .border-top-0;
  @extend .p-3;
}
```

Comment: It gets invisible for me b/c of `tab-pane` . Removing it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using just bootstrap that aligns content to nav-tabs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container border-right border-left border-bottom">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem possimus in temporibus nemo dolorem? Nemo quibusdam, rem deleniti adipisci eveniet voluptas enim provident voluptates voluptate sit! Similique voluptatem accusamus officia?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 5 using `box-shadow` for `.tab-content` may work, since `.nav-tabs` is using it too.

```
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #b1b4b6, 1px 0px 0px #b1b4b6, -1px 0px 0px #b1b4b6,
    -1px 1px 0px #b1b4b6, 1px 1px 0px #b1b4b6, 1px -1px 0px #b1b4b6,
    -1px -1px 0px #b1b4b6;
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following code to achieve it :
JSfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/SLFB8/)

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
outline:0;
 }
}
```