# border on bootstrap tabs content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, right-to-left

I want to add a border to my tab content.  There should be no border at the bottom of the selected tab. I found this questions: [how to give a border to bootstrap tab contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316559/how-to-give-a-border-to-bootstrap-tab-contents), but the answers didn't work for me?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sub_cats_8">תתי קטגוריות</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#category_8">קטגוריה</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="tab-content" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="category_8" class="tab-pane fade in active category" style="background-image: url('example.jpg');">
        <h1> קוסמטיקה </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sub_cats_8" class="tab-pane fade">
        <ul class="sub_categories">
            <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=11">איפור</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    direction: rtl;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
.nav-tabs {
    direction: ltr;
}
#logo {
    background-color: #005CB8;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    padding: 4% 10%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 10px 20px #003972;
    -moz-box-shadow: 20px 10px 20px #003972;
    box-shadow: 20px 10px 20px #003972;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}
#logo h1, #logo h4 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: head;
}
#logo h1 {
    font-size: 550%;
}
#logo h4 {
    font-size: 220%;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #477199;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active {
    background-color: #003972;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background: #003972;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #324F6B;
    color: white;
}
.category {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 15% 0;
}
.category h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: head;
    font-size: 500%;
    text-shadow: 2px -2px black;
}
.category_start {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
}
.sub_categories {
    -webkit-columns: auto 3;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: auto 3;
    /* Firefox */
    columns: auto 3;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.category_start .container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.product_image {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
.products_sub_list {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 80%;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.products_sub_list td {
    width: 15%;
    max-width: 15%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 3px solid #46617A;
}
.product {
    width: 80%;
    border: 3px solid #46617A;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.product_table td {
    border: 2px solid #46617A;
    padding: 13px;
}
.product_table {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.product_table td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.page {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border: 2px solid #46617A;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #C8D0D7;
}
.register {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
.register td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
.register table {
    margin-right: 240px;
}
#register {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #0066FF;
    background-color: #CCE0FF;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#bbg {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.tab-content {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ep2drocb/7/

Notice there is border in the open tab, also the closed tabs have a double border.

Comment: Can you post your code (and a JSFiddle if possible) so we can help you troubleshoot your issue. Otherwise, there is no way to know why that answer (in the Stackoverflow link you posted) did not work for you.

Comment: ok, i edit, i paste the new code, just move the space from the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is the `pull-right` on the `ul` element.

1. Remove `pull-right` class from the `ul`
2. Remove the `clear-fix` element as it's not needed anymore
3. Remove top border from your `tab-content` class
4. Float the `li`s right
5. Correct the margins on the tab anchors

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#category_8">תתי קטגוריות</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sub_cats_8">קטגוריה</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="category_8" class="tab-pane fade in active category">
        <h1> קוסמטיקה </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sub_cats_8" class="tab-pane fade">
        <ul class="sub_categories">
            <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=11">איפור</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.tab-content {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px; /* Removes the top border */
    padding: 1px;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
    float: right;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ep2drocb/9/

That should get you on the right track.

Comment: tanks, works fine, tell me something, where do you learn this stuff? because next time i want to do it my self, and i look at the documentetion at http://getbootstrap.com/ , and there nothing there

Comment: @NatiVaknin Feel free to mark this as the answer and upvote it.  To be able to solve this, there really is only one prerequisite. A keen understanding of what CSS does to render your page - specially with floats, positions, and display property variations.  A good understanding of the box model will go a long way as well.  The developer console in your browser is your best troubleshooting tool - learn to use it and understand what its telling you.  Good luck.

Comment: ok thanks, where do i mark this as the answer and upvote it? edit: i dont have the reputation to vote it

Comment: buy the way, do you know any good documentation for bootstrap?

Comment: The website you mentioned http://getbootstrap.com is the official documentation and is quite good, but you can also just download the source code from github and get more familiar.

Comment: but they dont write there anything about right tabs and things like that, only short things...